# Weird behaviour of 3d-transformed and animated element in OS X Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-animations

I'm having a hard time debugging a 3d-transformed element in Safari. The element in question starts behaving strangely when a 3d transform is applied through `@keyframes` animation. It's all fine when the animation is removed and a 3d transform applied directly.

**Good behaviour** (table resizes correctly, middle cell stays in the middle, all browsers OK):

```
#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5em;
  left: 50%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform:
            translateX(-50%)
            translateZ(-100px)
            rotateX(5deg) 
            rotateY(-10deg) 
            rotateZ(5deg);
  transform:
            translateX(-50%)
            translateZ(-100px)
            rotateX(5deg) 
            rotateY(-10deg) 
            rotateZ(5deg);
  width: 150vw;
  height: calc(10em + 110vh);
  //-webkit-animation: anim 5s ease-out 1 forwards;
  //animation: anim 5s ease-out 1 forwards;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fallenartist/aafj2h0w/1/

**Wrong behaviour in Safari only** (table resizes and moves uncontrolably to left and right when resizing a browser window):

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform:
            translateX(-50%)
            translateZ(-100px)
            rotateX(5deg) 
            rotateY(-10deg) 
            rotateZ(5deg);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform:
            translateX(-50%)
            translateZ(0)
            rotateX(-5deg) 
            rotateY(10deg) 
            rotateZ(-5deg);
    }
}
@keyframes anim {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform:
            translateX(-50%)
            translateZ(-100px)
            rotateX(5deg) 
            rotateY(-10deg) 
            rotateZ(5deg);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform:
            translateX(-50%)
            translateZ(0)
            rotateX(-5deg) 
            rotateY(10deg) 
            rotateZ(-5deg);
    }
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5em;
  left: 50%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
  width: 150vw;
  height: calc(10em + 110vh);
  -webkit-animation: anim 5s ease-out 1 forwards;
  animation: anim 5s ease-out 1 forwards;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fallenartist/aafj2h0w/2/

Why is animation with exactly the same transform values causing the element to behave differently in Safari?